# Occured ASSERTION FAILED in chttp2_transport.cc

Tags: grpc-c++

The following ASSERTION FAILED occurs on the gRPC server.

E0214 13:55:50.495956981 3596 chttp2_transport.cc:2900] ASSERTION FAILED: t->next_bdp_ping_timer_handle != TaskHandle::kInvalid

The server will terminate abnormally.
What could be the cause?

OS: CentOS 7.9
gRPC/C++ v1.61.1

I want to prevent the gRPC server from terminating abnormally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The location (chttp2_transport.cc) where it occurs is inside the gRPC framework.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc
ASSERTION is set because it is predicted that an unintended situation will occur. I would like to know the situation.

Please teach me.